# Android FacebookSDK login with native Facebook app installed asks for permissions even after the user have already given them

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Condition: Android device with native Facebook apk installed but logged out.

Every time this condition is met and the user tries to login using either Facebook's [LoginButton](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3/LoginButton/) or doing it manually (see below), after logged in, the Facebook SDK always asks for permission to access the user data, even if the user has already given permission.

Here is the code I'm implementing on my application:

**Version 1 - Login Button:**

XML:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email", "user_groups");
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        //modify interface or something
    }
};
```

**Version 2 - Manually**

XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
    android:text="Login" />
```

Java:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email", "user_groups");

public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("botaoOnClick");
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        System.out.println("session: " + session);
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(PERMISSIONS).setCallback(callback));
    }
    else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        //modify interface or something
    }
};
```

Even the sample apps that come with sdk works this way, but I have already seen some other apps (eg. Foursquare) working the way I think is the natural behavior (**only asks for permissions if the user hasn't already given them**).

So, does anyone know a way to achieve the desired result? Preferably without editing the Facebook SDK itself.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**: Additional information: upon checking the session variable on the callback method, the permissions always come empty when the condition above is met. If the user refuses to give permission (not for the first time), and tries to login again, the session comes with the permissions the user already gave some time in the past, as expected.

**Edit 2 (on 2013-06-28)**: I've decided to upload a video reproducing the issue, since I am not so sure everyone understood what I've meant in my explanation.

Link here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4qJfoiVSsU

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to avoid the `setPermissions()` calls or the problem is that every time the dialog for accepting the permission appears on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Thats probably because you got a signature mismatch between your app (which I assume is in debug mode) and your facebook app associated to your appID.

Basically you should make sure that:

1. The signature of your android app that use the facebook sdk is added to the [facebook app dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)
   [image: Facebook App Dashboard]
   you can easily get your app signature by using keytool or by adding this code in your activity's onCreate method :

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   try {
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
               getPackageName(), 
               PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
       for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           Log.d("TAG", "Hash to copy ==> "+ Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
           }
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

   } 
   catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

   }
   }
   ```
2. Facebook Login checkbox is Enabled
3. If your not enabling sandbox mode you need to choose a category from the app detail page
4. By default the loginbutton use the SingleSignOn loginbehavior, which will basically log you in as the owner of the facebook app, I suggest you to use the one that allow any user to log on in behalf of your facebook app. To do so, just add this line after you set the permission to the login button:

   ```
   loginButton.setReadPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
   loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
   ```

If you still having troubles, I suggest you to read this doc [troubleshooting facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#troubleshooting)

PS: And FYI, If you use UiLifecycleHelper, don't forget to override the main activity/fragment lifecycle methods, and forward the calls to the UiLifecycleHelper as stated in the javadoc.

> When using this class, clients MUST call all the public methods from the
>    * respective methods in either an Activity or Fragment. Failure to call all the
>    * methods can result in improperly initialized or uninitialized Sessions.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Facebook displays an error message at login if there's a signature mismatch.
Moreover, Facebook cannot check the signature when not installed. If the issue appears without Facebook app, that cannot be a signature mismatch.

Comment: First there was no error message at all and not facebook app installed when I tried to reproduce the problem, so you are probably misunderstanding something here. Second the asker stated that Facebook app was installed on his device. The FacebookSDK is completed independant from the Facebook APP, at least for the authentication workflow

Comment: This solution only works if I use the login behavior SUPRESS_SSO, which forces the user to login using the webview, else the same problem still occurs. Thanks for replying though!

Comment: I've edited my question and added a link to a video reproducing the issue (without the SUPRESS_SSO and using the LoginButton version as the manual button reproduces exactly the same behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the read permissions are requested every time (or just showing a pop-up saying they're already granted), if the Facebook app is not installed on the device.

It should be the behavior with the last Android SDK.

Did you notice that with the app installed too?

Comment: I've only noticed that with the Facebook app installed.

Comment: I've edited my question and added a link to a video reproducing the issue (using the LoginButton version as the manual button reproduces exactly the same behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I use the manual version with a slight twist to the if statement in your buttonOnClick function.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
boolean isReadAllowed = checkPermissions(Arrays.asList(PERMISSIONS), session.getPermissions());
if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(PERMISSIONS).setCallback(callback));
} else {
    if (isReadAllowed) {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
    } else {                                    
        session.requestNewReadPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList(PERMISSIONS)).setCallback(callback));
    }
}
```

And my checkPermissions function:

```
public static boolean checkPermissions(List<String> needed, List<String> available) {
    boolean ret = true;
    for (String s : needed) {
        if (!available.contains(s)) {
            ret = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

My flow works and only asks for permissions if they have been not been granted. Can you paste more of your callback code? I can check if you are doing something different there.

EDIT: Thank you for the video. I didn't understand the problem initially. I have seen this behavior before, and it is a bug with the Facebook SDK. I filed a bug on  their tracker ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/658583907501001)) a month ago, doesn't look like they are going to fix it.

Comment: I've edited my question and added a link to a video reproducing the issue (using the LoginButton version as the manual button reproduces exactly the same behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I have identified two causes for this problem.

1. Need to pass permissions in else block in manual version of your code i.e. openActiveSession(), For this I am using openForRead(op) with permissions.
2. KeyHash not matching, in this case also login successful in default facebook but every time shows permissions dialog.

I have created KeyHash using debug.keystore with following command

```
keytool -exportcert -alia
s androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | ope
nssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email", "user_groups");

public void buttonOnClick(View v) 
{
    Log.e("SKFBDemo", "buttonOnClick");

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && !session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) 
    {

        Log.e("SKFBDemo", "Session is in Active");
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(PERMISSIONS).setCallback(callback));
    }
    else 
    {
        Log.e("SKFBDemo", "Session is null or not opened or closed");

        OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
        op.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);

        session = new Builder(this).build();
        session.addCallback(callback);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(op);
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() 
{
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
    {
        Log.e("SKFBDemo", "Session.StatusCallback state="+state.toString());
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.e("SKFBDemo", "onActivityResult resultCode="+resultCode);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == Session.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_CODE)
    {
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession(); 
        if (session != null && !session.isClosed()) 
        {
            Log.e("SKFBDemo", "Login successful");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("SKFBDemo", "Facebook session not opened");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with this code, its asking permission dialog only once and working fine.

Comment: I've edited my question and added a link to a video reproducing the issue (using the LoginButton version as the manual button reproduces exactly the same behavior).